# Ruby on Rails - find how many groups each_slice has "generated"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, each

I am using `each_slice` to *group* my records inside different `divs`. How can I find out how many *div/groups*, `each_slice` has generated and add the *group* number inside each div.

**Example**

```
array = ["A", "B", "C", "D"]

- array.each_slice(2)

**Result =>**

%div.main-div
 %h1 DIV 1
 %div
  %h1 A
 %div
  %h1 B 

%div.main-div
 %h1 DIV 2
 %div
  %h1 C
 %div
  %h1 D
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this

```
slicer = array.each_slice(2)
groups = slicer.count
slicer.with_index {|a, i| p "#{i + 1}: #{a}" }
```

Comment: Tnx @Ursus. Could you please help me out with the html so I get it right. Html for `with_index`. Don't need to be something big. Thanks in advanced

Answer (score 1):

`array.each_slice(2).count` will return the number of groups generated.

Comment: Tnx @rii  How can I find which __group/slice__ the `div` belongs to. As in he example `Div 1`, `Div 2` etc